# How to reorder columns of pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to reorder the `hsp_treatment_df` dataframe based on the column name in ascending order for each patient ID, where:

- if the numeric value **after** the first underscore is the smallest, the column comes first, regardless of the time
- if the numeric value **before** the first underscore is the smallest (i.e., time), the column comes first; likewise if the value is largest, it comes last

In the column names, the substring before the first underscore is the time, and the substring after the first underscore is the patient ID. For example, in `12h_P1_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor` :

- 12h represents the time (t)
- P1 represents the patient ID (pid)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Analyse time points for each patient
## Get the patient ID from each column 

for cols in hsp_treatment_df.columns:
  pid = cols.split('_', 2)[1]
  pid = pid.lstrip("P") # get patient ID without the "P" substring

  time = cols.split('_', 2)[0]
  time = time.rstrip(time[-1]) # get time without the "h" substring

  # Rearrange the columns so that for each "pid", the "t" is in ascending order
  if (min(pid)) and (min(time)):
    c = []
    c.append(cols)
    hsp_treatment_df.columns = c
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-f48ee0e3d3de> in <module>()
     13     c = []
     14     c.append(cols)
---> 15     hsp_treatment_df.columns = c

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/base.py in _validate_set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
     56         elif new_len != old_len:
     57             raise ValueError(
---> 58                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
     59                 f"values have {new_len} elements"
     60             )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 29 elements, new values have 1 elements
```

Dataframe:

```
`hsp_treatment_df.iloc[:,0:12].head().to_dict()`

{'0h_P1_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '9.25',
  'DNAJC14': '8.44',
  'DNAJC15': '8.66',
  'DNAJC30': '7.34',
  'DNAJC9': '7.62'},
 '0h_P2_T1_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '9.26',
  'DNAJC14': '8.34',
  'DNAJC15': '8.63',
  'DNAJC30': '7.42',
  'DNAJC9': '7.19'},
 '12h_P1_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.58',
  'DNAJC14': '8.64',
  'DNAJC15': '8.98',
  'DNAJC30': '7.2',
  'DNAJC9': '7.23'},
 '12h_P2_T4_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.94',
  'DNAJC14': '8.38',
  'DNAJC15': '8.03',
  'DNAJC30': '7.32',
  'DNAJC9': '7.26'},
 '24h_P1_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.13',
  'DNAJC14': '8.43',
  'DNAJC15': '8.33',
  'DNAJC30': '7.41',
  'DNAJC9': '6.68'},
 '24h_P2_T5_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.85',
  'DNAJC14': '8.54',
  'DNAJC15': '8.73',
  'DNAJC30': '7.26',
  'DNAJC9': '7.49'},
 '48h_P1_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '9.05',
  'DNAJC14': '8.27',
  'DNAJC15': '7.63',
  'DNAJC30': '7.46',
  'DNAJC9': '7.42'},
 '48h_P2_T6_TimeC3_PIDC3_Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.57',
  'DNAJC14': '8.23',
  'DNAJC15': '8.6',
  'DNAJC30': '7.45',
  'DNAJC9': '7.62'},
 '4h_P1_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.25',
  'DNAJC14': '8.69',
  'DNAJC15': '8.78',
  'DNAJC30': '7.53',
  'DNAJC9': '7.29'},
 '4h_P2_T2_TimeC2_PIDC1_Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '9.49',
  'DNAJC14': '8.47',
  'DNAJC15': '8.7',
  'DNAJC30': '7.41',
  'DNAJC9': '7.23'},
 '8h_P1_T3_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '8.49',
  'DNAJC14': '8.58',
  'DNAJC15': '8.22',
  'DNAJC30': '7.29',
  'DNAJC9': '7.13'},
 '8h_P2_T3_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor': {'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': '9.16',
  'DNAJC14': '8.13',
  'DNAJC15': '7.88',
  'DNAJC30': '7.58',
  'DNAJC9': '7.18'}}
```

Expected output:

| Gene Symbol | 0h_P1_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor | 4h_P1_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor | 8h_P1_T3_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor | 12h_P1_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor | 24h_P1_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor | 48h_P1_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor | 0h_P2_T1_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor | 4h_P2_T2_TimeC2_PIDC1_Survivor | 8h_P2_T3_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor | 12h_P2_T4_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor | 24h_P2_T5_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor | 48h_P2_T6_TimeC3_PIDC3_Survivor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DNAJC9 | 7.62 | 7.29 | 7.23 | 7.13 | 6.68 | 7.42 | 7.19 | 7.23 | 7.18 | 7.26 | 7.49 | 7.62 |
| DNAJC30 | 7.34 | 7.53 | 7.29 | 7.2 | 7.41 | 7.46 | 7.42 | 7.41 | 7.58 | 7.32 | 7.26 | 7.45 |
| DNAJC14 | 8.44 | 8.69 | 8.58 | 8.64 | 8.43 | 8.27 | 8.34 | 8.47 | 8.13 | 8.38 | 8.54 | 8.23 |
| DNAJC15 | 8.66 | 8.78 | 8.22 | 8.98 | 8.33 | 7.63 | 8.63 | 8.7 | 7.88 | 8.03 | 8.73 | 8.6 |
| DNAJB6 /// TMEM135 | 9.25 | 8.25 | 8.49 | 8.58 | 8.13 | 9.05 | 9.26 | 9.49 | 9.16 | 8.94 | 8.85 | 8.57 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) with a `key` function that extracts patient ID and time, puts the patient ID first and adds the [zero filled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill) the time:

```
def key_fun(idx):
    new = idx.str.extract(r'(\d+)h_P(\d+)')
    return pd.Index(new[1] + new[0].str.zfill(2))

df = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=key_fun)
```